# How to show in a view using foreach, laravel?

Tags: laravel, foreach

this is the blade.php

```html
<h1> Cadastro de clientes </h1>

<hr/>

@if(count($cliente)>0)
<ul>
@foreach($cliente as $cliente)
    <li>{{$nome->nome}}</li>
    <li>{{$endereco->endereco}}</li>
    <li>{{$email->email}}</li>
    <li>{{$celular->celular}}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
@else
    <h4>Não há clientes</hr>
@endif
```

This is the model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

Use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cliente extends Model{

    protected $table = 'cliente';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

and this is the controller:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Cliente;

class CadCliController extends Controller {

    public function cadCli() {
        $cliente = Cliente::all();

        $array = array('cliente'=>$cliente);


        return view('cadCli', $array);
    }
```

I'm unable to show the table on foreach. keep showing the error that variable nome is undefined. Could you please help?....................................................................................

Comment: There is no 'nome' variable passing to your view, where you want your view to grab it from ?

Comment: from the table cliente

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to change your @foreach loop. In a typical @foreach loop, you are looping through a group of records to display information about each singular record. This is why typically, you will see `@foreach($records as $record)`.

I'm not sure what the singular version of 'cliente' is in your language, so I used `client`. Then, you are calling the `nome`, `endereco`, etc. from the individual client record. See if this @foreach helps:

```
@foreach($cliente as $client)
    <li>{{$client->nome}}</li>
    <li>{{$client->endereco}}</li>
    <li>{{$client->email}}</li>
    <li>{{$client->celular}}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: just because i created the table and the model named cliente. Thanks, it helped.[

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are returning a group of elements, be consistent with the variables names that you use (use `clientes` instead of `cliente`):

```php
class CadCliController extends Controller {

    public function cadCli() {
        $clientes = Cliente::all();

        return view('cadCli', ['clientes' => $clientes]);
    }
}
```

Now, in your view If you see in your `@foreach` statement, you are doing this:

```html
...
@if(count($cliente)>0)
    <ul>
    @foreach($cliente as $cliente)
        <li>{{$nome->nome}}</li> // <---------
        <li>{{$endereco->endereco}}</li> // <---------
        <li>{{$email->email}}</li> // <---------
        <li>{{$celular->celular}}</li> // <---------
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@else
...
```

As you can see, those variables (`$nome`, `$endereco`, etc) doesn't exist because you are defining every item of the `$clientes` array as `$cliente`, so I thing those are attributes of each object:

```php
...
@if(count($cliente)>0)
    <ul>
    @foreach($clientes as $cliente)
        <li>{{$cliente->nome}}</li> // <---------
        <li>{{$cliente->endereco}}</li> // <---------
        <li>{{$cliente->email}}</li> // <---------
        <li>{{$cliente->celular}}</li> // <---------
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@else
...
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. How do i print them side by side? loops? because i'm doing as a list.

Comment: @HeitorMourão do you mean like a table?